# Transpile errors with cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Tags: android, cordova, typescript, npm, ionic2

I want to use the [cordova file transfer plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/). I'm using it through the [Ionic-Native transfer module](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/transfer/).

The app won't run because there is a transpile error with the file transfer plugin and the [file plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/):

```
transpile started ... 
typescript: plugins/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/types/index.d.ts, line: 9 
Cannot find type definition file for 'cordova-plugin-file'. 

L8:  * @param server            URL of the server to receive the file, as encoded by encodeURI().
L9:  * @param successCallback   A callback that is passed a FileUploadResult object.
L10: * @param errorCallback     A callback that executes if an error occurs retrieving the FileUploadResult.
```

I installed `@types/cordova-plugin-file` through npm, but the app won't run because of duplicate identifiers in the two cordova-plugin-file packages:

```
transpile started ... 
typescript: node_modules/@types/cordova-plugin-file/index.d.ts, line: 376 
Duplicate identifier 'PERSISTENT'. 

typescript: node_modules/@types/cordova-plugin-file/index.d.ts, line: 377 
Duplicate identifier 'TEMPORARY'. 

typescript: plugins/cordova-plugin-file/types/index.d.ts, line: 376 
Duplicate identifier 'PERSISTENT'.     

typescript: plugins/cordova-plugin-file/types/index.d.ts, line: 377 
Duplicate identifier 'TEMPORARY'.
```

What is the right approach here?

Comment: as far as I know, Ionic2 native module is using own type definitions for file-transfer, could you pls clearify your case to get reproduction steps?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, it looks like the typings in cordova-plugin-file-transfer are incorrect.

It should be an external module but it is currently a script file (copied from DefinitelyTyped directly).

On the other hand, since cordova-plugin-file already includes its own typings, you don't need to install @types/cordova-plugin-file.

I experienced this issue as well.

However I was able to **work around** the issue with the following operations:

Setup :

````
```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.2.1
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v7.7.4
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002

```
````

Initial Problem :

````
```
$ ionic build ios

Running 'build:before' npm script before build

> apoc@ build /Users/js/dev/apoc-ochem/app_v3/apoc
> ionic-app-scripts build

[01:47:59]  ionic-app-scripts 1.2.1 
[01:47:59]  build dev started ... 
[01:47:59]  clean started ... 
[01:47:59]  clean finished in 2 ms 
[01:47:59]  copy started ... 
[01:47:59]  transpile started ... 
[01:48:04]  typescript: plugins/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/types/index.d.ts, line: 9 
            Cannot find type definition file for 'cordova-plugin-file'. 

       L8:  * @param server            URL of the server to receive the file, as encoded by encodeURI().
       L9:  * @param successCallback   A callback that is passed a FileUploadResult object.
      L10:  * @param errorCallback     A callback that executes if an error occurs retrieving the FileUploadResult.

[01:48:04]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[01:48:04]  Error: Failed to transpile program 
Error: Failed to transpile program
    at new BuildError (/Users/js/dev/apoc-ochem/app_v3/apoc/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/errors.js:16:28)
    at /Users/js/dev/apoc-ochem/app_v3/apoc/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:102:20
    at transpileWorker (/Users/js/dev/apoc-ochem/app_v3/apoc/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:68:12)
    at Object.transpile (/Users/js/dev/apoc-ochem/app_v3/apoc/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:26:12)
    at buildProject (/Users/js/dev/apoc-ochem/app_v3/apoc/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/build.js:98:78)
    at /Users/js/dev/apoc-ochem/app_v3/apoc/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/build.js:46:16

npm ERR! Darwin 16.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/js/.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.4/bin/node" "/Users/js/.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.4/bin/npm" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v7.7.4
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! apoc@ build: `ionic-app-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the apoc@ build script 'ionic-app-scripts build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the apoc package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ionic-app-scripts build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs apoc
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls apoc
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!

 /Users/js/dev/apoc-ochem/app_v3/apoc/npm-debug.log
```
````

Steps for Work Around:

1. Remove Platform
2. Remove Cordova plugin
3. Rebuild project
4. Add Platform
5. Remove cordova-plugin-file-transfer plugin
6. Rebuild ios project

   ````
   ```
   $ cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-file-transfer
   Removing "cordova-plugin-file-transfer"
   $ ionic build ios

   ...
   ...


   [02:01:20]  lint finished in 3.70 s 
   Error: No platforms added to this project. Please use `cordova platform add <platform>`.


   $ ionic platforms add ios
   ````

   Adding ios project...
   Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:

   ````
   Path: platforms/ios

   Package: com.nielssievertsen.apocsocial
   Name: apoc social


   iOS project created with cordova-ios@4.3.1


   Installing "com.synconset.imagepicker" for ios


   Installing "cordova-plugin-camera" for ios


   Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-compat" via npm


   Installing "cordova-plugin-compat" for ios


   Installing "cordova-plugin-console" for ios


   Installing "cordova-plugin-device" for ios


   Installing "cordova-plugin-device-motion" for ios


   Installing "cordova-plugin-facebook4" for ios


   Installing "cordova-plugin-googleplus" for ios


   Google Sign-In prerequisites

   START Running hook to add iOS Keychain Sharing entitlements (required since iOS 10)

   Will add iOS Keychain Sharing entitlements to project 'apoc social'

   END Running hook to add iOS Keychain Sharing entitlements (required since iOS 10)

   Installing "cordova-plugin-media-capture" for ios


   Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-file" via npm


   Installing "cordova-plugin-file" for ios


   Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-compat" already installed on ios.


   Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-compat" already installed on ios.


   Installing "cordova-plugin-nativestorage" for ios


   Installing "cordova-plugin-shake" for ios


   Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-device-motion" already installed on ios.


   Installing "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" for ios


   Installing "cordova-plugin-statusbar" for ios


   Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ios


   Installing "cordova-sqlite-storage" for ios


   installing external dependencies via npm

   npm install of external dependencies ok

   Installing "ionic-plugin-keyboard" for ios


   Installing "phonegap-plugin-push" for ios


   Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" in config.xml. Adding it to the project


   Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-file-transfer@~1.6.1" via npm


   Installing "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" for ios


   Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-file" already installed on ios.

   $ cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-file-transfer


   Uninstalling cordova-plugin-file-transfer from ios
   Removing "cordova-plugin-file-transfer"
   "cordova-plugin-file" is required by (cordova-plugin-media-capture) and cannot be removed (hint: use -f or --force)
   "cordova-plugin-compat" is required by (cordova-plugin-camera, cordova-plugin-media-capture) and cannot be removed (hint: use -f or --force)


   $ ionic build ios


   ............
   ...

   ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
   ```
   ````

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the typings in `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` is incorrect.

It should be an external module but it is currently a script file (copied from DefinitelyTyped directly).

You should file an issue there.

On the other hand, since `cordova-plugin-file` already includes its own typings, you don't need to install `@types/cordova-plugin-file`.

Comment: The strange part about this for me is that it simply makes the plugin completely unusable, but I can't find any references to this issue anywhere. How could that be? Anyways, I'm filing an issue.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the "plugin/" folder is cordova plugins for ionic2, which you may not need to perform typescript compilation,

You can always ignore the index.d.ts by specifying the exclude target from tsconfig.json

Answer (score 1):

For Ionic there is file called tsconfig.build.json

in it compiler option add below parameter.

```
 "skipLibCheck": true
```

it should look like this

```
{
  "extends": "...anytest....",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es5",
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "...your config here..."
  ]
}
```