# Error 2430: Interface 'InAppBrowser' incorrectly extends interface 'Window'.... In TypeScript Cordova Project After upgrade to TypeScript 2.4:

Tags: cordova, typescript

Full error message:

> Interface 'InAppBrowser' incorrectly extends interface 'Window'.  Types of property 'addEventListener' are incompatible.    Type '{ (type: "loadstart", callback: (event: InAppBrowserEvent) => void): void; (type: "loadstop", cal...' is not assignable to type '{ (type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, useCapture?: boolean): void; (type...'.      Types of parameters 'type' and 'type' are incompatible.        Type '"batterystatus"' is not assignable to type '"loadstart"'.

My TypeScript Cordova project compiled fined before I installed TypeScript 2.4.1 for Dev14. Now I get above error.

Answer (score 1):

Update the following Cordova DTS files with content in the corresponding link to the Definitely Typed GitHub. Copy and paste contents of corresponding files

- cordova-plugin-battery-status.d.ts ([update content](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/cordova-plugin-battery-status/index.d.ts))
- cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.d.ts ([update content](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.d.ts))

This is a breaking change as in TypeScript 2.4 we change how variant work in callback parameter. More detail [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#stricter-variance-in-callback-parameters)

Comment: I still have the same problem with the 1.7.0 version of this plugin.

node_modules\@types\cordova-plugin-inappbrowser\index.d.ts(27,11): error TS2430: Interface 'InAppBrowser' incorrectly extends interface 'Window'.

Comment: The links are dead, I wasted enough time on trying to find them... I gave up deleted InAppBrowser.d.ts out of my project, tried compiling failed, there was a single reference, I deleted that reference boom... works perfect

Comment: The links are still dead so the solution is useless. @xer21 posted a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57972192/10058447

Added **"skipLibCheck": true** in **tsconfig.json**:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "target": "es5",
    "skipLibCheck": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I face this issue in Apache Cordova in Visual Studio and tried to solve it by updating cordova from Update and extenstions link.